# How to export PYTHONPATH for every directory from python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have script which I have executed manually like

```
python create.py
```

but before I set PYTHONPATH like

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/create.py
```

Now I need to deploy ( execute script create.py 100 times from different directories)
If I have list of directories and in every `create.py` copied how to make python script which is going to execute all of them ( I now to iterate and enter in right and call `subprocess`) but how to export `PYTHONPATH` for every directory from python ?

Comment: Why can they not just perform python PATH/TO/SCRIPT/create.py or move to the directory?

Comment: why do you need to change the `PYTHONPATH`? You don't need to alter it just because you're running a script in a different directory...

Comment: @MatttDMo it imports more relative located modules and use parameters from those to create something

Comment: Have you tried `python /path/to/create.py`?  The script's directory is prepended to `sys.path` and imports will locate other scripts in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using virtualenv, you should probably also be using virtualenvwrapper, in which case you can use the add2virtualenv command to add paths to the Python path for the current virtualenv

```
add2virtualenv /path/to/
```